# CSS Button Image Change on Select/Active?

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling with this for the last couple of hours and can't seem to figure it out so any assistance would be amazing

I currently have a set of CSS tabs that change the content depending on which one you click which work perfectly, however I'd like for the tab image to change based on the users selection... for example

the fiddle is here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Fd4yc/1/

If it helps, I believe it's this code that affects the hover/active;

```
  [id^=tab]:checked + label {
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
    top: 0;
    padding: 3px;
  }

  [id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] {
      display: block;
  }
```

If the 3 tab images have a white background, I'd like them to have a black background when hovered over or active.

PS. I understand how to change the image if selected, but that same image is applying to all 3 tabs.

Added for Jan:

```
          .tabs label {
              display: block;
              padding: 1px 1px;
              border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
              color: #ffffff;
              font-size: 14px;
              font-weight: normal;
              font-family: 'Roboto', helveti;
              background: #transparent;
              cursor: pointer;
              position: relative;
              top: 2px;
              -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
              -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
              -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
              transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
              }
              #tab1 + label {
                  background-image: url('http://coins4fut.com/media/wysiwyg/xboxgrey.png');
                  }
                  #tab1 + label:hover {
                  background-image: url('http://coins4fut.com/media/wysiwyg/xboxgrey_HOVER.png');
                  }
                  #tab1:checked + label {
                  background-image: url('http://coins4fut.com/media/wysiwyg/xboxgrey_ACTIVE.png');
}
```

This still doesn't work ;\ its as if i've changed nothing

Comment: Perhaps you could refine your JSfiddle with **actual** images.

Comment: Also `<center>` is not now a valid HTML element as it has been deprecated.

Comment: Didn't think that would affect the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use an image with a transparent background? Then you can simply apply a background color to your label.

Otherwise you will need to set a background image for each label in CSS:

```
.tabs label {
    width: 169px;
    height: 44px;
}
#tab1 + label {
    background-image: url('http://coins4fut.com/media/wysiwyg/xboxgrey.png');
}
#tab1 + label:hover {
    background-image: url('http://coins4fut.com/media/wysiwyg/xboxgrey_HOVER.png');
}
#tab1:checked + label {
    background-image: url('http://coins4fut.com/media/wysiwyg/xboxgrey_ACTIVE.png');
}

/* Repeat for tabs 2 and 3 */
```

... and remove the `img` tag in the HTML:

```
<li style="color: transparent;">
    <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked="checked" />
    <label for="tab1"></label>
    ...
</li>
```

Comment: I've updated the fiddle with the current images, and the hover images are basically the same but have a blue background
http://jsfiddle.net/Fd4yc/1/

Comment: So your problem is to only change the background image of one, not all, labels on hover? Then you can use the ids. Can you get in more detail otherwise?

Comment: It's actually the opposite, i need it so a different hover/active image is used when each one is selelected, otherwise it will use the same image for all 3 labels

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. When tab1 is selected it gets its own "selected-image" and tab2 and tab3 use the same "not-selected-image"? Does this mean even the text on the image is the same?

Comment: I've added some extra code to the question to show you what i've done so far 

Thanks

Comment: Of course, if you set the image using css, you need to remove the `img` tag. Otherwise it will overlay the background image.

Comment: The image is set as <label for="tab1"><img src="http://myshop.local/media/wysiwyg/xboxgrey.png" alt="" /></label>

Comment: When you apply the image using CSS `background-image` as in my example, you need to remove the `img` ta because otherwise it you won't see the background image.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much you can do with the approach you're taking.  the best way to achieve the effect you're after is either using two different images and swapping them with css/javascript or using transparent images (i.e. only the icons and text are apparent) and changing the background CSS.  I'd recommend the latter since it's the closest to what you have already.

Aaalllthough, if you're in a cowboy mood: in this particular case (because you used grey-scale images) you could use the invert filter, but it's only supported in chrome/safari (webkit-based browsers).

Apply it in your CSS like so:

```
[id^=tab]:checked + label {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  padding: 3px;
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

As an aside, I felt the need to give you a few tips:

Lesson 1: the 'font' element is deprecated, so use 'span' instead for this kind of thing (it's an in-line element, like 'font' was).

Lesson 2:  doesn't have an HTML5 equivalent, so use 'auto' on your left and right margins to center-align things (only works on elements with a specific width, set this in CSS).

Lesson 3: don't use inline styles, put it all in CSS.  Adding 'style' attributes makes it harder to read/maintain and harder to help you! :)

Lesson 4: don't use so many IDs, use css classes instead.  You should only really use IDs sparingly.

Good luck!